# How to load comma delimited file with comma as a value to Hive

Tags: hive, delimiter

I'm getting comma in a field in a comma separated file. Kindly help me to load the file to Hive.
E.g :

```
Name,Description,Date
Gupta,Shradha,she is crazy,30/04/2017
Lokesh Ch,he is good,30/04/2017
```

Gupta and Shradha shoud be fit under "Name" field.

Kindly help.

Comment: Won't happen unless we can assume that there are no commas in `Description`.

Comment: P.s. by all means - use ISO date format (YYYY-MM-DD)

Answer (score 0):

Place all values inside double quotes(like "Gupta,Shradha","she is crazy","30/04/2017") and use OpenCSVSerde to parse the data file

include below properties in create table statement

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   "separatorChar" = ",",
   "quoteChar"     = "\""
)
```